# canvas overlap the button click

Tags: android, android-layout, canvas

Basically, I've created "button click" on the canvas bitmap layout, but after compile the coding, I can't see my button click, is it overlapped? Can I know what should I do seems even I change the `(w,h)size` but it also the same.

I guess i have to put all the code here for better understanding.

Here is my sample code(MainActivity.java):

```
package com.abcdrawing2;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends View {

    private Bitmap  mBitmap;
    private Canvas  mCanvas;
    private Path    mPath;
    private Paint   mBitmapPaint;
    private Paint   mPaint;

    public MainActivity(Context c) {
        super(c);

        mPath = new Path();
        mBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);

        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mPaint.setDither(true);
        mPaint.setColor(0xFF00FF00);
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.MITER);
        mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(8);
    }
    public void color_Clicked(View sender)
    {
        mPaint.setColor(0xFFFF0000);
    }

protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);

}

protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);

    canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
}

private float mX, mY;
private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 4;

private void touch_start(float x, float y) {
    mPath.reset();
    mPath.moveTo(x, y);
    mX = x;
    mY = y;
}
private void touch_move(float x, float y) {
    float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
    float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
    if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
        mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX)/2, (y + mY)/2);
        mX = x;
        mY = y;
    }
}
private void touch_up() {
    mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
    // commit the path to our offscreen
    mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
    // kill this so we don't double draw
    mPath.reset();
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    float x = event.getX();
    float y = event.getY();

    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            touch_start(x, y);
            invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            touch_move(x, y);
            invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            touch_up();
            invalidate();
            break;
    }
    return true;
}

public void clear(){
    mBitmap.eraseColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    invalidate();
    System.gc();
}}
```

AND ( Scribble.java)

```
package com.abcdrawing2;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Scribbler extends Activity {
    MainActivity drawView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        drawView = new MainActivity(this);
        drawView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        setContentView(drawView);
        drawView.requestFocus();
    }}
```

Comment: try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17043042/clear-canvas-in-button-click) way

Comment: i don't find useful from the link you send just now, whereby to show the button click or limit the canvas layout so button can be shown or not overlap by canvas.