# How do I clear the canvas in my custom android view?

Tags: android, canvas

Newbie to Android, struggling with updating canvas in custom view.

This may have a very simple answer, but so far I have not found it! I draw a path of about 2000 points the first time through onDraw. That is fine. Then the path changes, and I need to draw the new path, and get rid of the old path. But everything I try results in the old path remaining.

I thought there would be a simple 'clear canvas' call but no. I found a reference to [`_graphics.removeAll(_graphics);`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17043042/clear-canvas-in-button-click) but that gives me build errors cannot resolve reference etc.. So is that a valid call, and how do I get it to build? Or is there a simple way !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most simple way, is to just fill the canvas with the background color of your choosing.

```
c.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
```

If you are looking for canvas transparency, you can also use this

```
c.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR)
```

Comment: Ok - turns out to be a real face-plant moment - concentrating so much on the background, forgot the obvious - to reset() my Path!! Thanks for reinforcing the view that it IS simple - helped to refocus me on the basics.